# Angular 8 material chips. Only allow user to add 1 chip

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
I'm trying to make so users can only choose one chip in my angular material chip list.
```

When I start typing in the input, a process goes to the backend and retrieves a list of options, based on what's typed

I've tried using the [multiple] = false, as the documentation suggests, https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api but I'm still able to select more than one result.

```
<mat-form-field class="double-field" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{translations.companyLbl}}</mat-label>
            <mat-chip-list #companyChip [multiple]="multiple">
              <mat-chip *ngFor="let company of companiesLoaded" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
                (removed)="removeCompanyChip(company)">
                {{company.Name}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="companyLocked">cancel</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip>
              <input placeholder="Choose a company" #companyInput [formControl]="companyControl" formControlName="Company"
                [matAutocomplete]="companyAutocomplete" [matChipInputFor]="companyChip"
                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" />
            </mat-chip-list>
            <mat-autocomplete #companyAutocomplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectedCompanyChip($event)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies | async" [value]="company">
                {{ company.Name }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Users should only be able to choose one result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add this to your chip input tag

```
<input (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
```

Write the logic in your add function

```
add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add your company if array's length is 0
    if (this.companiesLoaded.length === 0) {
      this.companiesLoaded.push(value.trim());

    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to add custom chips. I think this logic should be used in the (optionSelected) caller. It's working fine, thanks a lot!.